# Firebase response - null values response

Tags: android, spring, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase notifications in my android app and spring backend.

Everything was working fine, but maybe something gone wrong after I release my android version to google play store for testing. Now I have this response:

```
FirebaseResponse{multicast_id=0, success=null, failure=null, canonical_ids=null, results=null}
```

The notifications are sent and everything works fine, but why I am getting a null values in my Spring backend?

My backend java spring code:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/send", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
   produces = "application/json")
   public ResponseEntity<String> send() {


    JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
    try {

        body.put("to", "/topics/photos");
        body.put("priority", "high");


        JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();
        notification.put("body", "body string here");
        notification.put("title", "title string here");


        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        data.put("lat", "value1");
        data.put("lng", "value2");

        body.put("notification", notification);

        body.put("data", data);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(body.toString());

    CompletableFuture<FirebaseResponse> pushNotification = androidPushNotificationsService.send(request);
    CompletableFuture.allOf(pushNotification).join();

    try {
        FirebaseResponse firebaseResponse = pushNotification.get();
        if (firebaseResponse.getSuccess() == 1) {
            log.info("push notification sent ok!");
        } else {
            log.error("error sending push notifications: " + firebaseResponse.toString());
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(firebaseResponse.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>("the push notification cannot be send.", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

I get nullpointer here, which is null success:

```
firebaseResponse.getSuccess()
```

What is the cause? I have topic "photos" defined in my project firebase console. What can be the issue, beside everything was working good till today? Really strange for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have more then one deployment environment set and when you launched the application in play store you changed to production and in firebase you only added the data in development. This once was a problem for me, I only set the data in dev and when I released one version to the client, the app was without any data (Staging was empty).